# Difficulty creating a content grid layout using css and html

Tags: css, html, grid, css-float

I am trying to create a grid layout using  tags and css. I need the grid system to hold four main blocks as portrayed in the image below. I have created a solution that works great in safari and chrome, but not so well in firefox as the titles overlap. 
Please see my code below, and maybe someone can see where I have gone wrong! I cant for the life of me find the problem.

[image]

HTML CODE:-

```
<div class="elements_wrapper">

         <div id="element1">
           <img class="align-image" src="img/image1"/>                                          
               <span class="element-title">Title</span>
                   <p class="element-explain">Main text goes here</p>
         </div>

         <div id="element2">
           <img class="align-image" src="img/image2"/>                                          
               <span class="element-title">Title</span>
                   <p class="element-explain">Main text goes here</p>
         </div>

         <div id="element3">
           <img class="align-image" src="img/image3"/>                                          
               <span class="element-title">Title</span>
                   <p class="element-explain">Main text goes here</p>
         </div>

         <div id="element4">
           <img class="align-image" src="img/image4"/>                                          
               <span class="element-title">Title</span>
                   <p class="element-explain">Main text goes here</p>
         </div>                                          
    </div>
```

CSS CODE:-

```
.elements_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-65px;
    margin-top:110px;   
    padding-bottom:30px;
}


#element1{
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:30px;
    padding-bottom:20px;

}


#element2 {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:30px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}


#element3 {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:545px;
    margin-top:200px;
    padding-bottom:20px;

}


#element4 {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:545px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

.element-title {
    font-family:helvetica, arial, serif;
    color:black;
    display:inline;
    font-size:14pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:15px;
}

.element-explain {
    font-family:helvetica, arial, serif;
    font-size:10pt;
    float:left;
    width:280px;
}


.align-image {
    border: none; 
    float:left; 
    padding-right:15px;
}
```

My code works great in safari and chrome, but not that well in firefox, please help. Also, please let me know if the code I have already used is bad or needs changing to ensure cross browser compatibility. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the next example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZNSAX/2/

Comment: This was amazing. Thank you so much. I've learnt alot from your exmaple and ill definitely be using this technique again in the future. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
.element-explain {
    font-family:helvetica, arial, serif;
    font-size:10pt;
    float:left; 
    width:280px;
}
```

Floating left here will cause this error.  Firefox is a bit finicky with floating elements than Chrome and IE.  Removing this should fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for taking time out and reading my question and providing an answer. By doing as you said, the titles fixed into their right positions which was great, however, the element-explain content started overflowing into the element block below. Thanks anyway.