# How to create a simple grid panel layout using HTML/CSS within Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I'm trying to create a simple 4 panel grid using HTML in Shiny but can't get it to work. Though there are somewhat related posts like [Difficulty creating a content grid layout using css and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253707/difficulty-creating-a-content-grid-layout-using-css-and-html) referencing a solution at http://jsfiddle.net/ZNSAX/2/, these are pure HTML done outside of Shiny.

The first image below shows what the output looks like on R Studio browser and Edge browser, while the second image is a crude rendering of a 4 panel grid that I'm trying to get to.

I have fooled around with so many forms of `fluidRow(...)`, `column(x,...)`, `class = "panel panel-default",style="width: 60px"`, `tags$div(class = ...)`, I wonder if I've exhausted all possibilities!

Below is simple reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           div(class = "panel panel-default",
               div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 1"),
               div(class = "panel-body", "panel 1 id")
           ),
           div(class = "panel panel-default",
               div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 2"),
               div(class = "panel-body", "panel 2 id")
           )
           
    ),
    column(6,
           div(class = "panel panel-default",
               div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 3"),
               div(class = "panel-body", "panel 3 id")
           ),
           div(class = "panel panel-default",
               div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 4"),
               div(class = "panel-body", "panel 4 id")
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? You can simply adjust the width (I set it to `60%`) and the gap between the child divs (I set it to `2rem`) in the parent div.

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(htmlwidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style = "margin-top: 2rem; width: 60%; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; gap: 2rem;",
      
      
      div(class = "panel panel-default",
          div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 1"),
          div(class = "panel-body", "panel 1 id")
      ),
      div(class = "panel panel-default",
          div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 2"),
          div(class = "panel-body", "panel 2 id")
      ),
      
      div(class = "panel panel-default",
             div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 3"),
             div(class = "panel-body", "panel 3 id")
         ),
      
      div(class = "panel panel-default",
             div(class = "panel-heading", "Panel 4"),
             div(class = "panel-body", "panel 4 id")
         )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I see, jettison fluidRow(...), column(...), the standard Shiny layout functions, and go straight to HTML. Another thing to learn! THANK YOU I've been pulling my hair out over this small, fiddly, but important thing,